# I have worked in this job longer than I have/had ever worked in any other job

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

**I think these are correct.**

> 1 I have worked in this job longer than I **have** ever **worked** in any
> other job.
>
> 2 I have worked in this job longer than I **had** ever **worked** in any
> other job **before**.
>
> 3 I have worked in this job longer than I ever **worked** in any other
> job **before**.

I think this wrong

> 4 I have worked in this job longer than I **have** ever **worked** in any
> other job **before**.

Do you agree?

Comment: (2) is incorrect, (4) is OK.

Comment: I thought that "before" shows that the current period, during which the speaker has worked, is not part of the experience which took place BEFORE it. Go figure!

Comment: A native speaker will hear #4 as grammatical or ungrammatical according to how they understand **before**, since **before** can be understood as "before now" (thus involving the present) or "in the past" (thus excluding the present).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(2) doesn't work because the tenses don't match.

(1), (3) and (4) are all valid sentences. *Before* means 'before my present job'. Strictly speaking it isn't necessary, because *ever* conveys the meaning 'at any time in the past' - but the combination *ever before* is often used for emphasis.

Comment: Thank you! I thought 2 to mean "I have worked in this job longer than I had ever worked in any other job before I started working here".

Comment: "I have worked here longer than I have ever worked..." or, if you have left that job "I **had** worked there longer than I **had** ever worked..."

Comment: @KateBunting why do the tenses have to match? What if I wanted to compare the length of work between two different timelines?

Comment: The perfect tense refers to a past event  in relation to a later, but still past, event. So you could say "Before starting work here, I had worked for four other companies."